# IONIC AdMob Insert Ad In Ion-List

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, admob, user-experience

I'm trying to place an AdMob ad in my app without being obnoxious to the user.  Currently, I can only find a way to have a banner ad locked at the top or bottom of the screen, which is beyond annoying and moves around the nav/tab bars.  I believe the best way to do this is to display the ad at a certain index in a list within my app.  So say I have a list of 10 items, I'd like the ad to be inserted after the 5th item of the list.

The problem is that I'm unsure of whether I can insert an AdMob ad based on html with the cordova-plugin-admobpro plugin.

Here's what I'd like to attempt:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="article in articles" class="item-borderless">
    <a class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap" href="#" ng-click="goToArticle(article)">
        <img src="{{article.urlToImage}}" class="fit-thumbnail">
        <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
    </a>

    <ion-item ng-if='$index === 5' class="item-borderless">
        <!-- INSERT AD AFTER THE 5th ITEM -->
    </ion-item>

  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Currently, I'm only aware of using the "position" attribute to position ads.

```
AdMob.createBanner({
    adId:admobid.banner, 
    position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.TOP_CENTER, 
    autoShow:true
});
```

If anyone has any idea on how to achieve the results I'm looking for, it would be appreciated.

Comment: don't think this is possible using cordova

Comment: I have seen this happening in apps such as truecaller. Not sure how it is being done.

Comment: any update here .. Im also facing same issue.

Comment: any update on this?  I need the same functionality